# I cannot figure out use $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity to do this question.

Tags: analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta

Use the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity to prove that the function $f: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x) = x^2$ is continuous at $x = 1$.

First, I am having trouble understanding **what is the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity** then how to use that to figure out how to start and finish the proof.

Comment: Note that $|x^2-1|=|x-1||x+1|$ and $x$ is close to $1$

Comment: Consider $(1+e)^2 = 1+e^2+2e$. If $|e|<\delta<1$  for some $\delta$ then $e^2 < |e|$. Thus
$$ 1-2\delta < (1+e)^2 < 1+3\delta $$
Given some $\epsilon>0$ try to find such a $\delta$ so that both $2\delta$ and $3\delta$ are at most $\epsilon$.

Comment: The statement that $(M,d)$ is a metric space is irrelevant to this proof.

Comment: I would start by stating the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity and then working with $|f(x)-f(a)|$ until you get an inequality with a term that is relatively simple and small. Then set that term to be less than $\varepsilon$ and that is more or less your $\delta$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$|x^2-1|=|x+1||x-1|\leq (1+2|1|)\delta$
$\displaystyle \Rightarrow \delta<\frac{\varepsilon}{1+2|1|}=\frac{\varepsilon}{3}$